# Guardar imagen en Galería de fotos con Android Q y anterior

Tags: android

Tengo una imagen en un ImageView que me gustaría guardar en la Galería de fotos del dispositivo.

```
minSdkVersion 16
compileSdkVersion 29
targetSdkVersion 29
```

He encontrado muchas formas de hacerlo navegando en Internet y al final, he seguido la solución de [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57357175/how-to-save-image-to-camera-folder-in-android-q).

```
private void downloadImage() {
    BitmapDrawable draw = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = draw.getBitmap();
    try {
        saveImage(bitmap);
        // La foto ha sido descargada
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // No se pudo descargar la foto
    }
}

private void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {
    String folderName = "MY_APP";
    String imageName = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm").format(new Date());
    String mimeType = "image/jpeg";

    OutputStream fos;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, imageName);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, mimeType);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "DCIM/" + folderName);
        Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
        fos = resolver.openOutputStream(imageUri);
    } else {
        String imagesDir = Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
                .toString() + File.separator + folderName;

        File file = new File(imagesDir);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            if (!file.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "file.mkdirs() has failed!");
            }
        }

        File imageFile = new File(imagesDir, imageName + ".jpeg");
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }

}
```

El comportamiento que recibo es el siguiente:

- En el emulador, la foto se descarga pero no se visualiza en la Galería instantáneamente. Debo proceder a cerrar por completo la Galería para poder visualizar la foto.
- Al tratar de descargar la foto más de 1 vez, la misma se sobrescribe, es decir, no guarda varias imágenes. En el código se proporciona un nombre con un *timestamp* para evitar esto, pero sucede.
- En un dispositivo real con Android 8.0.0 la foto no se descarga en absoluto.

En adición a lo anterior, el objetivo es tener la imagen en la Galería del dispositivo donde se encuentran ubicadas todas las demás imágenes públicamente. En el código anterior, se proporciona un *nombre de carpeta* y no entiendo la razón ya que nuestra intención no es tener las imágenes en una carpeta propia de la aplicación.

Objetivo:

1. Descargar la imagen en la Galería de fotos del dispositivo para que esté disponible para otras aplicaciones.
2. Soportar API 16 hasta API 29.
3. Habilidad de guardar varias imágenes al presionar el botón de descargar más de una vez.

Sin más, gracias de antemano por la ayuda brindada.

Answer (score 0):

Para guardar imágenes en versiones anteriores a Android Q, que comentas que la foto no se descarga en absoluto, prueba a añadir lo siguiente en el else, después de fos.close():

```
Content contentValues = ContentValues();
contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, file.absolutePath);
yourContentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Comment: La clase `Content` no puede ser encontrada. Alguna idea?

Comment: No entiendo qué ocurre, en android Q y posteriores usas la clase content... podrías poner el Log?

Comment: Literalmente solo indica que no se encuentra la clase Content desde que agrego las líneas. Recuerda que estoy agregando el código para versiones menores a Android Q.

Comment: Pues no sé qué puede pasar, este código lo he sacado de un proyecto dónde me ha tocado realizar esta funcionalidad para antes y después de AndroidQ, y desconozco por qué no encuentra el content :(